# Using System.IO.directory.getfiles

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the following code to get a list of pdf's and place them in an array, I am then searching them using autocomplete extender.  Everything works fine but System.IO.directory.getfiles always returns the path of the file which I dont want.

Any ideas.

```
    Public Shared Function GetCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
    'Create array of movies   
    Dim files() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\pdfs")

    ' Return matching movies   
    Return (
         From m In files
         Where m.Contains(prefixText)
         Select m).Take(count).ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this LINQ to remove the path from the fullfilename list returned

```
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\pdfs", "*.pdf").Select(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s))
```

Please, also note that Directory.GetFiles could retrieve just the PDF if you use the right overload

Comment: lol, I did wonder as it didnt work the first time.  Works now perfectly thanks.  What do you mean the right overload as I am looking to open the selected pdf

Comment: Your question code uses GetFiles to retrieve all files in the directory C:\PDFs, mine will filter to only files with PDF extension in that directory. As you can see from [Directory.GetFiles docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) there are three different overloads for this method, you use the first one, my answer the second one

Comment: ok thanks, Whilst Im here I may as well ask, how do I then open the file once it had been selected in the textbox?

Comment: Probably it is better that you post another question. It will be more visible and will receive more attention

Answer (score 0):

So you want the filename instead of the full path?! Use the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
Dim files() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\pdfs")
Dim names = From path in files
            Let fileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(path)
            Where fileName.StartsWith(prefixText)
            Select fileName  Take count
```

Note that i've used `StartsWith` instead of `Contains` since the variablename `prefixText` suggests that this is more appropriate.